# Is COM a Windows equivalent to D-Bus for IPC?

Tags: com, ipc, dbus

I'm transferring my developing environment from *nix to WIN. GUID-based COM seems to be a dominant IPC mechanism in WIN, so is it an equivalent to UUID-based D-Bus?

Comment: A GUID is a UUID (.i.e 128-bits things), but I'm not sure what you're after exactly

Comment: I mean is COM a Windows equivalent to DBUS? I'm working on a Windows project which works with COM. And I've been working on similar projects on Linux which works with DBUS. So I thought, if there is an equivalence, maybe I can port my understanding of the high-level architecture without digging to much into the IPC details.

Comment: From 10000 feet above, yes. In reality, there's nothing common. There are may ways to do IPC on Windows: RPC, COM, named pipes, sockets, etc. your question is too broad for an answer. You'll have to dig a bit more.

Comment: Very first line in the DBus documentation: "If you use this low-level API directly, you're signing up for some pain".  That's not really different in Windows, there are countless service bus libraries that try to hide the pain.  COM is not on the top of that list, not anymore.  If you are comfortable with the DBus pain then you could just use their Windows port.

Comment: Have you tried to use D-Bus there?